# Let $X_1$ , $X_2$ , $X_3 $ ... be independent random variables, with $P[X_n=1]=p_n $and $ P[X_n=0]=1-p_n $

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, independence, borel-cantelli-lemmas

Let $X_1$ , $X_2$ , $X_3  $ ... be independent random variables, with $P[X_n=1]=p_n $and $ P[X_n=0]=1-p_n$. Show that

> (a) $X_n $ converges to $0$ in Probability iff lim $p_n$ goes to $0$.
>
> (b)  $X_n $ converges to $0$ almost surely iff $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} X_n $ converges.

Initially I found it is quit obvious by using definition.

For (a) Let assume $X_n $ converges to $0$ in Probability then by definition $P( |X_n| - 0 > \epsilon ) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, and that means $P(X_n=1) = p_n \to 0$ and vice versa.

For (b) Borel cantelli lemmas work right?

I really want know where I got wrong? If you provide your idea then I would be nice.

Comment: What do you mean "I really want to know where I got wrong"?

Comment: For (b) there is no need to use Borel-Cantelli.  It is an immediate consequence of the fact that $X_i \in \{0,1\}$.

Comment: @Michael The statement of (b) is actually: (b)  $X_n $ converges to $0$ almost surely iff $\sum p_n $ converges.

Comment: What about part (a) ?

Comment: It would be nice if you answered my "what do you mean" question.  Tho part (a) the def is $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}P[|X_n-0|>\epsilon]= 0$ for all $\epsilon>0$.